# How to tell whether mid 2010s Volvo XC70 actually needs maintenance?

Tags: maintenance, repair, volvo, scheduled-maintenance

How do I tell whether the Volvo XC70 actually needs maintenance or it's just the vendor attempting to earn more money? How do I self repair it and diagnose if I don't want to go to the vendor?

Comment: All machines need maintenance on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vehicle maintenance is based on time and distance travelled, so maintenance tasks are completed at particular distances or times.

At 5k, it may be change oil & filter,check brakes,

At 10k, it may be oil & filter, fuel filter, air filter, check brakes etc.

So there are time based tasks, such as checking anti-freeze concentration prior to winter and changing the brake fluid every 2 years (hygroscopic).

At any check if something is found wanting, then it should be corrected. Any "new" noise warrants checking it out.

The examples above are just an idea, not specific to any vehicle, Volvo will have produced a detailed maintenance schedule for your car, which you should follow. Searching gives many links, [this](https://www.volvomechanics.com/resources) may be a good place to start

The ecu (computer) has more recently been programmed to warn owners that x, y or z needs to be done. Some owners used to drive vehicles until they broke down, ignoring any interval so the manufacturers have started dealing with this.

Comment: I generally agree, 'tho I'd add that in addition to distance, _time_ is also a factor. For instance, brake fluid is hygroscopic and its performance declines over time; a car with few miles but several years may require brake fluid replacement.

Comment: @David will edit and add time. I spoke to my favorite garage and very few owners get the brake fluid changed... it **should** be changed every 2 years for most manufacturers...

Comment: Yes, I agree. I'm an outlier, and flush and replace brake fluid on my cars and bikes according to their maintenance schedules. Over the 55 years I've been doing this, I've never had to rebuild a master or slave or wheel cylinder. It's a mystery. <g>